# What is the difference between 'Deployed data' and 'Send data' in a contract creation transaction?

Tags: mist, contract-deployment

I'm following the 'Create your own cryptocurrency contract' on ethereum.org. I deployed the contract but I don't understand what does 'Deployed Data' and 'Send Data' represent. Is any of them the bytecode for the contract?[image]

Answer (score 1):

"deployed data" is the "contract bytecode"
and
"send data" is the data you provide to your contract (e.g the token parameters or functions calls or parameters)

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answer, the "deployed data" is the actual contract bytecode.

However, the "send data" in this context is the whole data that you send in order to deploy the contract.  This includes three parts:

- The constructor - this copies the deployed data into place and sets up the contract storage using the constructor args.  This does not form part of the final deployed contract.
- The deployed data - the contract bytecode.
- The constructor arguments.

You should be able to see the deployed data embedded within the send data.

There is another entity used when calling a contract after deployment which is the "call data" - this is the function selector and arguments for calling a contract's functions. When deploying a contract, the "call data" is replaced by the "send data".